# isBetween function in momentjs is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, date, momentjs

I have used this following function to return the dates that fall in between (-4) to (+2) hours of the date specified by the user(which is retrieved using the user id) but the isBetween function does not behave as expected! I am new to front-end programming and i am sorry if the answer is obvious.

````
 router.get('/result/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        // let udate = req.params.date;
        const user = await match.findById(req.params.id)
        let m = moment(user.date)
        console.log(m.toString())
        m1 = m.subtract(4, 'h');
        console.log(m1);
        m = moment(user.date)
        let m2 = m.add(2, 'hours');
        console.log(m2);
        const query = await match.find()
        query.map(a => {

            if (moment(a.date).isBetween(moment(user.date).add(2, 'h'), moment(user.date).subtract(4, 'h'))) {
                console.log(moment(a.date).toString);
            }
        })
        const list = await match.find({})
        res.json(list)
    } catch (err) {
        res.send('error: ' + err)
    }
})```


[the log of this code comes to be][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YihLX.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isBetween(m1, m2)` function checks the date *between* `m1` and `m2`.

Try to replace

`moment(a.date).isBetween(moment(user.date).add(2, 'h'), moment(user.date).subtract(4, 'h'))`

with

`moment(a.date).isBetween(moment(user.date).subtract(4, 'h'), moment(user.date).add(2, 'h'))`

Comment: thanks for helping. But i tried to implement the same functions with $lte and $gte while queriying.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the arguments matters

[isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

> Note that the order of the two arguments matter: the "smaller" date
>   should be in the first argument.
>
> ```
> moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25'); // true
> moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-25', '2010-10-19'); // false
> ```

Swap the order of the arguments you've passed

```
if (moment(a.date).isBetween(
  moment(user.date).subtract(4, 'h'),
  moment(user.date).add(2, 'h')
)) {
  console.log(moment(a.date).toString);
}
```